# Can't apply CssClass via C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I am trying to apply CssClass when validator is false, it worked for me in the past and now I don't know why it doesn't work.

Textbox:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPass"
    AutoPostBack="false" 
    ClientIDMode="Static" 
    runat="server"
    placeholder="Password (8 - 16 digits)" 
    CssClass="Text" 
    type="password" 
    ValidationGroup="check">
</asp:TextBox>
```

Validators attached to this textbox:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revPass"
    runat="server"
    Display="None" 
    ControlToValidate="txtPass"
    EnableClientScript="false"
    ValidationExpression="[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,16}"
    ValidationGroup="check">
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvPass"
    runat="server"
    EnableClientScript="false"
    ControlToValidate="txtPass"
    Display="None"
    ValidationGroup="check">
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

<asp:CompareValidator ID="cvPasswords"
   runat="server"
   ErrorMessage="Passwords do not match!"
   EnableClientScript="false"
   CssClass="error"
   ControlToCompare="txtPass"
   ControlToValidate="txtConPass"
   ValidationGroup="check">
</asp:CompareValidator>
```

But I have to say that only the last one works. The validators work, just not changing `CssClass`.
**EDIT:**
It is not even enteres the if statemant I checked it. there is the if statement:
`if (!(revPass.IsValid) || !rfvPass.IsValid)
{
    txtPass.CssClass = "txtError";
}`

Comment: Why not enabling client script? People want instant response on validation, nowadays.

Comment: did you apply `CssClass="error"` Attribute on all Validators .? i can see this only in last validation so that's why the last one works

Comment: @KanisXXX Yes, in the code I assigned for each textbox.

Comment: @modiX Is this the problem? because it works in other pages like that

Comment: @D4NieLDev No it's not, but if you enable client script it will validate on client and server. This will result in a faster response (since most have JS enabled), but it will require you to implement a solution for JavaScript, too. By default, ASP.NET will not add any class name, it will show a span-div, when not valid. That's why it does not work the way you want.

Comment: @D4NieLDev just for confirmation.. you want to change css of your Validations ..?? in short changing CSS of Error messages, right.?

Comment: I want that if the validator is false it will change his controltovalidate textbox cssclass

Comment: @KanisXXX look at my comment above

Comment: Your CompareValidator's "ControlToValidate" is "txtConPass". What control is that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to Apply Css on your Validator's Error messages Then you have to set `CssClass` Attribute of all Validators..

UPDATE :Sorry about that, i misunderstood your Question. Did you try this On Code behind

`protected void Button1_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsValid)
        {
            // code executed when validation are valid
        }
        else
        {
            txtPass.CssClass = "Your New Class";
            txtConPass.CssClass = "Your New Class";
        }
    }`

Comment: He wants to modify the class of the textbox

Comment: I dont want to change the errormassege cssclass I want to change the controltovalidate textbox of the validator cssclass

Comment: @D4NieLDev do you have only 2 TextBox on Form.?

Comment: Guys, it`s OK, I just changed the first textbox as you can see on the question. All is fine now, thanks for trying to help!